# Using Array.includes() instead of OR chain

Tags: javascript

Which is better? I'm concerned about both style/readability and performance.

```
someMathematicalExpression === 0 || someMathematicalExpression === 1 ||
 someMathematicalExpression === -1 || someMathematicalExpression === 11 || ...
```

vs.

```
[0,1,-1,11,...].includes(someMathematicalExpression)
```

The OR chain has the advantage of being more literal, whereas it might not be obvious from first glance what the intent of the .includes is.

On the other hand, the .includes can be much shorter, and it separates the solutions from the expression, making it easier to see which values will evaluate to `true`.
Most significantly, when someMathematicalExpression is fairly complex, the entire OR chain can become very operator-heavy, making it hard to read.

I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything, or check to see if there was a third option I hadn't considered.

**TL;DR: is there a reason to not use Array.Includes instead of an OR chain containing only === statements**

Comment: As for the intent, just call your array `solutions`; then `solutions.includes(expression)` seems pretty clear.

Comment: The more conditions you have, the more appealing `.includes` (or similar approaches) become. Also, this is not really a fitting question for SO, as it is about code style, and very opinion based.

Comment: @ASDFGerte It’s not primarily opinion-based, though. The OP’s asking about performance as well.

Comment: Performance is, in all normal cases, negligible - "premature optimization is the root of all evil" (Knuth). The performance difference is implementation dependent, and would involve very detailed analysis, but imho doesn't have much benefit.

Comment: @ASDFGerte sorry, bit new to SO. Should I delete the question, or is there a way to close it?

Comment: There is, but if people think it doesn't fit, it will be closed, and not really have any repercussions against you, so there is very little harm in just keeping it open. I merely expressed my personal opinion, that such questions are better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that site, thank you!

Comment: @Xufox Good suggestion, I'm going to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The third option would be

```
const value = someMathematicalExpression;
value === 0 || value === 1 || value === -1 || value === 11 || ...
```

which importantly evaluates `someMathematicalExpression` only once. It might also be faster than the `includes` because it can use short circuiting and doesn't need to evaluate the whole array of solutions, but a compiler might be able to optimise that away so it shouldn't matter unless this is a performance bottleneck where you need to benchmark anyway. (In which case you might also want to consider trying a static `Set` and a `has` check)

So keep your code DRY by not repeating the mathematical expression, whether you find the array + `includes` approach or the comparison chain more readable is left to your personal judgement. Of course, `includes` also has the drawback that it requires an ES6+ environment, that might matter for you or not.

Comment: Does 'includes' not usually short circuit?

Comment: Does `array.includes` continue evaluating the rest of the array once a match is found?

Comment: @MarkMeyer It doesn't continue looping over the values after it found a match, but the array literal `[0,1,-1,11,...]` has to be evaluated completely before `includes` is even called

Comment: If the entire boolean statement is being evaluated inside an Array.filter or Array.map, would this still work? I've never tried to create a variable inside of one before, for some reason I assumed it couldn't be done

Comment: @FallenAsleep Yes, you can put the entire statement into any function (including `filter` or `map` callback functions) and `return` the final expression - it will create a local `const value` variable in that function.